# Displaying a tag only for one element in a list. ember.js.(cloaked-collection, discourse)

Tags: ember.js, discourse

I have a source code(discourse) than I need to work with with `ember.js`. I am trying handle only one "post" (the first) in a list using `cloaked-collection`.

```
//topics.hbs
    {{#unless model.postStream.loadingFilter}}
            {{cloaked-collection itemViewClass="post"
                                 defaultHeight="200"
                                 content=postsToRender
                                 slackRatio="15"
                                 loadingHTML=""
                                 preservesContext="true"
                                 uncloakDefault="true"
                                 offsetFixedTop="header"
                                 offsetFixedBottom="#reply-control"}}
          {{/unless}}
//post.hbs
//some code here. 
//Then I want to insert <div class="uniw"></div> only on the first post
```

The question is: for the list of `itemViewClass="post"`, how can I check if I am in the first "post"? so that i can insert a piece if code.

Comment: [ember-cloaking](https://github.com/eviltrout/ember-cloaking) seems to be kind of an old  piece of code; that it depends on `Ember.View` which is already [deprecated](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html) as you can see. Since, `cloaked-collection` is not a component and does not seem to be providing a contextual-component usage; I am afraid you cannot achieve what you want. If your project is not a legacy application that you had to use `cloaked-collection`; I would suggest searching for and upgrading to a newer addon.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I have ended up doing my solution via javascript/jquery and inserting the element after the html has been rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [firstObject](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property_firstObject) to get first object of a collection. Something like this:

```
{{items.firstObject}}
```

Inside each block you can check index:

```
{{#each people as |person index|}}
  {{#if (is-equal index 0)}}
    {{person}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Note that is-equal is non-standard helper. You can get it from [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) addon or write it yourself

Comment: you could see that the code is using `cloaked-collection`. I am not sure how your solution would fit inside the code I have posted